# How does the Azure function URL is generated?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

Currently I have an Azure function in my development environment with the following URL:

`https://http-trigger-api-test.azurewebsites.net/api/TestHttpTriggerApi?code=AvAaWlH4Tw8kOXdQRuAqr8euweAf9/OUUc/cSdw9fq7uaAPZ8uj0bB==`

This function URL can be divided in 3 parts:
`http://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<funcname>?code=<functionkey>`

1. `<yourapp>`is the function app URL
2. `funcname` is the name of the function written in NodeJS, C#, Python, etc.
3. `<functionkey>` how is this code generated?

I am interested to know how the code from part 3 is generated and I am also curious to know if there is a way I can customize this code, i.e., `code=device01receive`.

Any idea or comment is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some authorization levels to Azure Functions like User, Function, Admin, Anonymous and System.
**To restrict the users authorization to our functions, some access keys can be generated by the azure.**

We get unauthorized when suitable keys are not passed to the function app URL. Based on the authLevel, we have to pass the keys in the URL.

**Anonymous** - no authentication is required. Any valid HTTP request passes
**Function** - **host** (master) and **function** keys.
**Admin** - requires a **host key** for authorization.
**System** - requires the **master key** of a function app for authorization.
**User** - requires a valid authentication token.

*Function*, *Admin* & *System* authorization level are **key based**.

For more information on authorization level usage in function app, refer [here](https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/12/04/azure-functions-http-authorization-levels/).

> I am also curious to know if there is a way I can customize this code, i.e., `code=device01receive`.

Go to Azure Portal > Your Function App > Functions (in the left index pane) > Select your published function app > click on function keys
[image]

From here, you can add your customized key to the specific function app.
I have created the key provided by you to my function and tested it.
**Output:**
[image]